# How to find the specified text in String in android?

Tags: android

I have a String Object which I need to check if it contains another string. It would something like checking if "Hello World" contains the world "World".

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains a substring containing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643683/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-containing-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect whether a particular string is contained within you're source string you can do this

`String source = "like here is the string "hellohowareyou" and i want to extract the world "how" ...it that possible how ????
android"
If(source.contains("here is the"))
   .....
else
   .....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once ... worked for me ....
Using the keywords

> contain

and

> toLowerCase()

You can achieve the solution you want... This way

```
String text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";

if(text .toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  String text = "Hello World.";

   if(text.contains("World')){
   //Do something
  }
  else {
 //Do something
 }
```